# How can I add some Meta in the head?

Tags: magento2, php, ultimo, magento-2.2.5

First, sorry for my mistakes, I am a new Magento developer.
So I made a litle module to make some social share buttons (Facebook, twitter, etc...) and so I have to add in the head some meta (for Open Graph).
I search everywhere on the internet and no answers are solving my problems.

How can I override the head ?

Everywhere I see "search for head.phtml..." but I search everywhere and I don't have any head.phtml.

I use Magento 2.2.5, and I have Infortis Ultimo theme.

Comment: can you add og tag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Create a custom child theme that uses the ultimo theme as a parent:

`app/code/design/frontend/YOURCOMPANY/YOURTHEME/theme.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<theme xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/theme.xsd">
    <title>YOURCOMPANY YOURTHEME</title>
    <parent>Infortis/ultimo</parent>
</theme>
```

2) create `app/code/design/frontend/YOURCOMPANY/YOURTHEME/registration.php` file

```
<?php
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
        \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::THEME,
        'frontend/YOURCOMPANY/YOURTHEME',
        __DIR__
    );
```

3) create `app/design/frontend/YOURCOMPANY/YOURTHEME/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml`

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <!-- favicons -->
        (...)

        <!-- Custom Metas -->
        <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#ffffff"/>
        <meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="icons/favicons/ms-icon-144x144.png"/>
        <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff"/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>

        <!-- ADD YOUR OTHER METAS HERE .... -->
    </head>
</page>
```

4) Enable your custom theme in the admin area.

5) Read up for more info: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-inherit.html